# Generating product of two Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have two Pandas DataFrame of unequal shape and I want to generate a resultant DataFrame containing the product of both. 
DataFrame 1:

```
X_D X_M X_Dt X_G
1   0   0    0
0   1   0    0
0   0   1    0
0   0   0    1
```

DataFrame 2:

```
S_D S_M S_Dt S_G
0   1   0    0
0   2   0    0
0   3   0    0
0   4   0    0
0   5   0    0
0   6   0    0
```

Resultant DataFrame:

```
X_D X_M X_Dt X_G S_D S_M S_Dt S_G
1   0   0    0   0   1   0    0
1   0   0    0   0   2   0    0
1   0   0    0   0   3   0    0
1   0   0    0   0   4   0    0
1   0   0    0   0   5   0    0
1   0   0    0   0   6   0    0
0   1   0    0   0   1   0    0
0   1   0    0   0   2   0    0
0   1   0    0   0   3   0    0
0   1   0    0   0   4   0    0
0   1   0    0   0   5   0    0
0   1   0    0   0   6   0    0
.
.
.
0   0   0   1   0   6    0    0
```

I was able to do it using brute force method but it is computationally very inefficient for a large number of sample. I want to know if there's a Pythonic way of doing it.

Comment: `df1.assign(key=1).merge(df2.assign(key=1)).drop('key', axis=1)`

Comment: @ayhan Why not post it?, it's good.

Comment: @U9-Forward It's a duplicate.

Comment: @ayhan True, realized too.